# db.getUser in node.js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What is the equivalent of the MongoDB shell command `db.getUser` and `db.getUsers` in Node.js MongoDB 2.x?
I see in the driver documentation that `db.addUser` and `db.removeUser` exist but no mention of `getUser` or `getUsers`.
The only alternative I have is to use the `db.command` (equivalent of mongo shell command `db.runCommand` AFAICT) with `usersInfo` command to find the users. This goes like this:

```
var cmd = { usersInfo: 'marty', db: 'DbName'};
db.command(cmd, function (err, r) {
 assert.equal(null, err);

});
```

Also to make sure there is no misunderstanding, the following [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548590/how-to-get-user-info-from-mongodb-in-node-js) does not answer the question since that person was using their own collection and not the db users. Unless I'm missing something in MongoDB and it works with DB users (which I would be glad if someone can clarify as well).

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: So what's wrong with running the command form? Not all shell helpers ( in fact very few outside of basic CRUD ) are implemented in drivers. Basically none of the administrative commands ( which this is ) are implemented in drivers.

Comment: @NeilLunn I find it odd that the db.addUser and db.removeUser are implemented but there is no way to get the user info and/or update it. It just makes these API functions useless IMHO. I'm rather new to MongoDB and trying to be consistent in the implementation. So I would either use the db.command for all operations or if there is a nicer alternative that comes with the driver, that would be preferred.

Comment: @NeilLunn I also have no idea whether it makes sense to make all these changes in an admin mode (ie, using db.command) - can the same role that can run the createUser, can also run db.addUser ?? just curious and a bit (overly?) cautious :)

Comment: Probably the best way to explain this is that **everything** is acually invoking `.command()` under the hood. That is all MongoDB requests are. So whether there is a helper built into the shell or not, there is always an underlying command request.

Comment: hmmm. Well, thanks for the clarification. So you're basically saying that the shell is rather a wrapper as well on-top of the `db.runCommand` command? meaning `db.getUsers()` is merely a `db.runCommand({usersInfo:1})` ... ? Either way you look at it, I think it would be good if it was properly mentioned in the driver's documentation. But, hey, thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is asked 5 years ago, I'd like to answer it now.
So I'm using mongodb native driver of version: 3.5.6 and here's my solution.

```
let mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

mongoClient.connect(function(err, client){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    client.db('dbName').command({usersInfo:1 }).then((userList)=>{
        console.log('user List',util.inspect(userList, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!